# Configuring the hostname on Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Tags: networking, centos, redhat

On RHEL and similar distributions such as CentOS and OEL you can set the hostname by adding a hostname entry in /etc/sysconfig/network.

> HOSTNAME=hydrogen.lan

If you don't have such an entry, the system will fall back to the default behaviour - referencing the hostname configured on the first matching entry in /etc/hosts.

> 192.168.92.101          hydrogen.lan hydrogen

Now, my question is. Are there any good reasons to use the direct hostname configuration in /etc/sysconfig/network or is it simply redundant in most scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The box in your example will have hydrogen.lan as its hostname, not hydrogen.

The only way I know of to have `hostname` return the short hostname and to have `hostname -f` return the FQDN, is to use *both* the mentioned options.

So add `HOSTNAME=mybox` to /etc/sysconfig/network and add

```
10.10.10.10 mybox.example.com mybox
```

to /etc/hosts. I like having `hostname` and `hostname -f` return different things. By default, Anaconda sets it up like you have it set up now.

Comment: I don't think it works that way. If the HOSTNAME= is set, that will be the FQDN regardless of what is in /etc/hosts. Your example will have hostname and hostname -f both return "mybox", at least on OEL5U4 where I just tested it.

Comment: You are quite right on the hostname being set to hydrogen.lan if that is the first none named in /etc/hosts. Going to try to reverse those and see what happens :)

Comment: Ok, reversing the order in /etc/hosts will give "hydrogen" as the hostname _and_ FQDN. It also very much seems like the HOSTNAME= entry will override anything in /etc/hosts for both hostname and FQDN.

Comment: Note that having a fully qualified hostname does not seem to break anything. dhclient presents itself to the dhcp server with hostname only, as does the login prompt and the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It will stop the hostname mysteriously changing when someone adds another entry (for a new web site, perhaps) to /etc/hosts (or eighteen months later when the machine is rebooted).

If the hostname is changed accidentally (by someone typing hostname then fat-fingering the return key) you can see what to change it back to.

Answer (score 0):

Running "hostname myhost" from the command line immediately changes the hostname.

I define the short or full hostname by editing /etc/sysconfig/network in order to make the name persistent across reboots.

Adding an entry in /etc/hosts with the system's IP address and FQDN and short name makes the hostname consistent for services that rely on it (apache, lpd, sendmail, etc.)

Comment: Sure, but may I ask why you choose to set the hostname in /etc/sysconfig/network rather than let the system get it's hostname directly /etc/hosts?

Answer (score -2):

the hostname command always worked for me
just type `man hostname`

Comment: Simply using hostname(1) will not make the change persistent.

Comment: There was no mention of persistency being a requirement. And in any case, these days you have to switch to using `hostnamed`

Comment: Nah, we'll be on Oracle Linux 6 for many years yet. Systemd 25 can go away and stay there, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Oracle Linux? Good luck with that